# Link to ORCID when revising a paper on editorial manager

Tags: software, elsevier, digital-researcher-id

When I started revising my paper on Editorial Manager, it required me to link to my ORCID (see the attached). I do have an ORCID account, and after I logged in, nothing happened, i.e., the ORCID was not linked.
I checked my ORCID account, and it listed the Editorial Manager there. Still, I couldn't proceed to build a PDF for the revision at the last step.

What's the solution?[image: My ORCID account]
[image: The 1st step to link ORCID]